# Application using SOAP webservices, signup functionality not working on client side

Tags: java, web-services, jsp, servlets, soap

Am creating a web application using SOAP web services in java. Sign up functionality works fine when I test through the test client at the server side however, at the client side when I fill in the details and click on signUp button the same page is getting refreshed but no action is being performed (data is not getting inserted into the database). When debugged, I saw that the code is failing at

```
 if(qdone.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
```

Could anyone please help me with this. I'm not knowing where am I going wrong.

Here is my code

signUp.jsp

```
        <%@ page contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"%>

        <!DOCTYPE html>

        <html>
        <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-capable" content="yes" />
        <meta name="viewport"
            content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
        <meta name="apple-mobile-web-app-status-bar-style" content="black" />

        <link href="Flat-UI-master/css/flat-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="Flat-UI-master/images/favicon.ico">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="Flat-UI-master/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/icon-font.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <div id="page-wrapper">
    <header class="header-11">
         <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">


    <div class="navbar-collapse collapse in" style="height: auto;">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="index1.html"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#explorer">College Explorer</a>
            <li><a href="#fundraiser">Fund Raisers</a></li>
            <li><a href="#fafsa">FAFSA</a></li>
            <li><a href="#studentloan">Student Loans</a></li>
        </ul>
        <ul class="nav pull-right">
        <li><a class="btn btn-primary" href="signIn.jsp">SIGN IN</a> </li>
        </ul>

    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        </div>
    </header>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <section class="header-11-sub bg-midnight-blue">
        <div class="background">&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <h3>Task Tracker</h3>
                    <p>Make your life easy having a task tracker</p>
                    <div class="signup-form">
                        <form id="form" method="post" action="signUp">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="username"
                                    id="username">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="password"
                                    placeholder="password" id="password">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="fname"
                                    id="fname">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="lname"
                                    id="lname">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input class="form-control" type="text"
                                    placeholder="email@example.com" id="email">
                            </div>
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Sign
                                    Up</button>

                                <a href='http://localhost:8080/FinalClient/View/signUp.jsp'
                                    class="btn btn-large btn-primary">Cancel</a>
                            </div>
                        </form>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
 </div>         
<script class="cssdeck"
    src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script class="cssdeck"
    src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js">   
 </script> 
 </body>
 </html>
```

signUp Servlet (signUp.java)

```
    package servlets;

    import java.io.IOException;
    import java.io.PrintWriter;

    import javax.jws.WebService;
    import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
    import javax.servlet.ServletException;
    import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
    import javax.servlet.http.HttpSession;

    import DefaultNamespace.ServiceProxy;

    /**
     * Servlet implementation class signUp
     */
    @WebServlet("/signUp")

    public class signUp extends HttpServlet {
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        ServiceProxy proxy =new ServiceProxy();


        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#HttpServlet()
         */
        public signUp() {
            super();
            // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        /**
         * @see HttpServlet#doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
         */
        protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            PrintWriter out =response.getWriter();
            response.setContentType("text/html");
            String qdone;
            try{

                String username = request.getParameter("username");
                String password = request.getParameter("password");
                String fname = request.getParameter("fname");
                String lname = request.getParameter("lname");
                String email = request.getParameter("email");

                if (!checkMandatorySignUpFields(username, password, fname, lname, email)) {
                    request.setAttribute("message", "Required Field Missing!");
                    String nextJSP = "/View/signUp.jsp";
                    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
                    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                }else {
                proxy.setEndpoint("http://localhost:8080/Final/services/Service");
                System.out.println("crossed the endpoint");
                qdone=proxy.signUp(username,password,fname,lname,email);
                System.out.println(qdone);
                System.out.println("signup qdone");
                HttpSession session =request.getSession();
                System.out.println("Session started");
                if(qdone.equalsIgnoreCase("true")){
                    System.out.println("qdone value obtained....signup successful");
                    session.setAttribute("userSession", session);
                    out.println("Welcome to CollegeTime Task planner" +username);
                    request.setAttribute("message", "Signup successful, Please login.");
                    String nextJSP= "/View/signIn.jsp";
                    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
                    dispatcher.forward(request, response);

                }else{
                    out.println(qdone.equalsIgnoreCase("false"));
                    out.println("\n <a href='http://localhost:8080/FinalClient/View/signUp.jsp'><br>Go back to Signup and try again</a>");

                    request.setAttribute("message", "Unable to Signup!" + qdone);
                    String nextJSP = "/View/signUp.jsp";
                    RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(nextJSP);
                    dispatcher.forward(request, response);
                }
                }

            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        private boolean checkMandatorySignUpFields(String username, String password, String fname, String lname, String email){
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return true;
        }

    }
```

Service.java (signup functionality) code at the Server side

```
    @WebService
    public class Service {
        DatabaseConnection db = new DatabaseConnection();

        String result="";
        public String signUp(String username, String password, String fname, String lname, String email){
            System.out.println("Inside SignUp");
            result=db.signUp(username, password, fname, lname, email);
            System.out.println("SignUp Successful");
            System.out.println(result);
            return result;
        }
```

Database query implementation for signUp at server side

```
    public String signUp(String username, String password, String fname, String lname, String email){
        int rowcount=0;
        String result = "";
        Calendar cal= Calendar.getInstance();
        String time = sdf.format(cal.getTime());
        try{
            String query="select * from user where username = '"+username+"'";
            ResultSet res;
            stm.executeQuery(query);
            res=stm.getResultSet();
            if(!res.next()){

            String insertQuery = "insert into user(username, fname, lname, password, email, lastlogin) values ('"+username+"', '"+password+"','"+fname+"','"+lname+"','"+email+"','"+time+"')";

            rowcount=stm.executeUpdate(insertQuery);
                if(rowcount>0){
                    result ="true";
                }
                else{
                    result="false";
                }
            }
    }catch(SQLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
        System.out.println(result);
    return result;
    }
```

Web.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
          <display-name>FinalClient</display-name>
          <welcome-file-list>
            <welcome-file>signUp.jsp</welcome-file>
          </welcome-file-list>
          <servlet>
            <description></description>
            <display-name>signUp</display-name>
            <servlet-name>signUp</servlet-name>
            <servlet-class>servlets.signUp</servlet-class>
          </servlet>
          <servlet-mapping>
            <servlet-name>signUp</servlet-name>
            <url-pattern>/View/signUp</url-pattern>
          </servlet-mapping>
          </web-app>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My issue was solved. Just posting, in case if anyone in future come across the same issue.

I dint give name attribute in the signUp.jsp form

**Previously in signUp.jsp:**

```
    <form id="form" method="post" action="signUp">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="username"
                                id="username">
                        </div>
```

**Later(Solution) in signUp.jsp (adding a name attribute):**

```
    <form id="form" method="post" action="signUp">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <input class="form-control" type="text" placeholder="username"
                                id="username" name="username">
                        </div>
```